# Yii2 set and get cache value using memcache

Tags: php, caching, yii2, memcached

I'm trying to get the cache value by key, in this case the value is "count". But sometimes I get the value and sometimes not. The lenght of the key is same. Where is problem?

```
   $cache = Yii::$app->cache;

    $q=  Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(24) . time() ;
    $key = 'captcha_value_' . $q;

    $cache->set($key, 'count');

    echo "<br/>$key: ".$cache->get($key)."";
```

that's what is output

```
     captcha_value_DgytIGlX-tagsEFzoDjcK5ao1574253702:count 
     captcha_value_6qNykCcw91KCSD2lJ0Trl_cY1574254788:
```

Comment: Have you tried using file cache or another cache storage engine?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The problem was that for some reason I had two Memcache servers. One with host is localhost, the other with host is memcache. And they replaced each other.

To solve this problem you need to specify in the file  common/config/main-local.php in cache helper method ReplaceArrayValue

```
'cache' =>  [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => new \yii\helpers\ReplaceArrayValue([
            [
                'host' => 'memcache',
                'port' => 11211,
            ],
        ]),
        'useMemcached' => true,
    ],
```